# How to be able to read source code of System.Reactive on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.reactive

## Intro.

I installed *System.Reactive* into my c# project and be using it's methods in the project.

So, I want to read source code of *System.Reactive* on *VisualStudio*.

## Question.

**How to be able to read the source code on *VisualStudio*?**

## Important notices

- I found source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) but it's too unless to read for me.
- I want to read source code body, but not signiture.
- I want to search definition of method used in my project by using F12-Key.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? That GitHub repo _is_ the source code. I don't understand what else you want?

Comment: `but it's too unless to read for me.` What does that mean?

Comment: `I want to search definition of method used in my project by using F12-Key.` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Navigate_from_Here__Decompiled_Code.html

Comment: Visual Studio supports obtaining source code for "not your code" via the Source Server protocol. If nobody has published the source to a [source server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/source-server-and-source-indexing), VS isn't going to do anything

Comment: @john i want to know how to do some setting visual-studio to read source code on msvs. However, it is not  setting for just reading, it is necessary to be able to jump from the method i use in my project to that definition with the F12-Key.

Comment: @mjwills  when i want to find definition of lib's method used in my code, on msvs i jump to the definition directly but on github i cant it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i see. if the source doesn't exists in any source server, i try to add ReactiveX project into my project and to build the project.

Comment: @all Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I decided to adopt the following method.

- Clone *ReactiveX* project from [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive)
- Build the project my self.
- Add reference of the dll and the project into my project.

By the way, as for the server, I could not find out about it, so I decided not to use it.